# How to Convert PATINDEX sql operation into pyspark sql engine

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have to migrate below SQL query statement below into pyspark SQL query.

```
select case when LEN(travel_time) = 1 then
concat('0' , SUBSTRING(travel_time,PATINDEX('% ^0 %', travel_time ), LEN(travel_time)+1),':00:00')
else concat( SUBSTRING(travel_time,PATINDEX('% ^0 ', travel_time ), LEN(travel_time)+1),':00:00') end as travel_time from sampleTable
```

[image]

above that output, the actual MS SQL providing the solution, we need similar to pyspark with PATINDEX operation.

Comment: dilip_df.select(
    concat(
        when(
            length(dilip_df['travel_time']) == 1,
            concat(
                lpad(
                    regexp_extract(dilip_df['travel_time'], r'\d+', 0),
                    2, '0'
                ),
                regexp_extract(dilip_df['travel_time'], r':\d+:\d+', 0)
            )
        ).otherwise(
            regexp_extract(dilip_df['travel_time'], r'\d:?\d:\d+', 0)
        )
    ).alias('travel_time')
).show()

Comment: we are using pyspark sql  engine, kindly if possible to help on that solution

Comment: You mean spark.sql?

Comment: yes, we are expecting spark sql query solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the below approach in pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lpad, regexp_extract, length, when
dilip_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1:15:00",), ("07:45:00",), ("0 2:23:00",), ("0 6:50:00",)],
    ['travel_time']
)
dilip_df.select(
    concat(
        when(
            length(dilip_df['travel_time']) == 1,
            concat(
                lpad(
                    regexp_extract(dilip_df['travel_time'], r'\d+', 0),
                    2, '0'
                ),
                regexp_extract(dilip_df['travel_time'], r':\d+:\d+', 0)
            )
        ).otherwise(
            regexp_extract(dilip_df['travel_time'], r'\d:?\d:\d+', 0)
        )
    ).alias('travel_time')
).show()
```

```
+-----------+
|travel_time|
+-----------+
|      15:00|
|      07:45|
|      23:00|
|      50:00|
+-----------+
```

The above code doing transformations on the '**travel_time**' column

If the length of '**travel_time**' is 1, it means there is only a single digit so

Extract the numeric part from the '**travel_time**' column using `regexp_extract`.
`Left pad` the extracted numeric part with zeros to make it a two-digit number using lpad.
Concatenate the padded numeric part with the rest of the original time string obtained by using `regexp_extract`.
If the length is not 1, it means there is more than one digit so
Extract the time part using `regexp_extract`.
The final result is an alias column named '**travel_time**' containing the transformed values.

Using Spark.sql:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
dilip_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1:15:00",), ("07:45:00",), ("02:23:00",), ("06:50:00",)],
    ['travel_time']
)
dilip_df.createOrReplaceTempView("dilip_table")
query = """
    SELECT 
        travel_time,
        CASE 
            WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(travel_time, '^\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$') IS NOT NULL THEN 'HH:MM:SS'
            WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(travel_time, '^0\\d{1}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$') IS NOT NULL THEN '0H:MM:SS'
            WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(travel_time, '^0\\d{1} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}$') IS NOT NULL THEN '0H HM:SS'
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS format
    FROM dilip_table
"""
result = spark.sql(query)
result.show()
```

In spark.sql code It selects the '**travel_time**' column with transformations applied using the `CONCAT` and `CASE` `WHEN` expressions based on the length of the '**travel_time**' column.
If the length is 1, it extracts and manipulates the numeric part of the '**travel_time**' using `regexp_extract`, `lpad`, and `concat`.
If the length is not 1, it extracts the time part using `regexp_extract`.

**Results:**

```
+-----------+--------+
|travel_time|  format|
+-----------+--------+
|    1:15:00|HH:MM:SS|
|   07:45:00|HH:MM:SS|
|   02:23:00|HH:MM:SS|
|   06:50:00|HH:MM:SS|
+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: select case when LEN(travel_time) = 1 then
concat('0' , SUBSTRING(travel_time,PATINDEX('% ^0 %', travel_time ), LEN(travel_time)+1),':00:00')
else concat( SUBSTRING(travel_time,PATINDEX('% ^0 ', travel_time ), LEN(travel_time)+1),':00:00') end as travel_time from sampleTable   -- this query will work excepted PADINDEX, if i using your changes, i am getting 00 only, also we needs 3 digit like 5:00:00

Comment: also, your code input should be 1 or 5 or 11 or 15 or 19 like that not 3 digit

Comment: i am expecting result as i posted image which is right side fourth column.

Comment: I have made changes in spark sql solution can you check if it helps

Comment: Select  case when len(regexp_replace('t15','[^0-9]','')) = 1 then concat('0',regexp_replace('tt1','[^0-9]',''),':00:00')
else concat(right(regexp_replace('tt15','[^0-9]',''),1),':00:00')
 end